# Why would a .sln file open as empty in VB2010Express when it should open referring to projects etc. as it did before?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-express, solution

Why would a .sln solution file open and appear empty in Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express - i.e. no windows showing projects and code files etc.

When I inspect the file in a text editor, it contains references to vbproj files (which are present) which indicate that it should not appear as empty.

No error messages are reported when the file is opened.

**Update:**
(To illustrate my problem)

It attempts to load the projects that belong to the solution:

[image: Loading projects]

And then results in a bare solution screen

[image]

Comment: So you're saying the solution explorer is empty? Or that there's no solution explorer at all?

Comment: +1 Yes, the main Visual Screen is nearly blank. There about one or 2 widgets which seem generic and not related to the project in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the projects did load for the solution but the Window to display them was not open or visible. To make it visible, go to the View menu and select Other Windows:

[image: menu option to open solution explorer]

This displays the *4* projects referenced by the solution

[image: solution explorer showing 4 projects in Visual Basic 2010 Express / Visual Studio Express]

Forgive me for blurring the project names but this might be commercially sensitive and therefore not for public awareness. But you get the picture.

In summary it was my lack of knowledge about the tool, though I had looked under the Window option first thinking along these lines, but the View menu is actually where one would go to display things about the project.

Thanks to everyone for your contributions.

Comment: Expecting to accept this as the answer, when I'm allowed to, tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Express Edition is limited to on project per solution. If you have more than that, you will not be able to use the solution file with the express edition of visual studio. You will need to open the projects separately.

Comment: Thank you but I disagree, in my situation there were four projects being referred to by this one sln file, i.e. 4 vbproj referred to by one solution. Using the free, Visual Basic *Express* 2010 all the time, so recenly I would guess that something appears to have gone wrong with one or more of the files for the solution to be blank now.

Comment: I've updated the question with screenshots. The first shows it attempting to load the 4 projects associated with the solution. Up until this problem this week, these 4 projects have been visible in the solution and Visual Studio Express was always the tool used. Moreover, if there was a deliberate limit to the number of projects per solution then wouldn't the tool explictly advise the developer of this with a pop up dialog or something?

Comment: As you will see from my answer, Express Edition does actually support multiple projects per solution, in my case four.